# Communicating with Serial Port using Adobe Flash

Tags: flash, serial-port

Just wondering if there is any way to access the serial port directly in adobe flash ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes -- using Zinc. http://www.multidmedia.com/ 
The process is a little bit longer though and you need extra software - Basically, you import Zinc's classes and call them via as3 to access the serial port. You publish flash, and then you publish the swf you just made through Zinc into a exe/app/linux binary

Answer (score 0):

Flash cannot access the serial port without assistance from some sort of external proxying mechanism.

Comment: I thought that might be the case, do you have any idea what proxys could help me out ?