# Error while interfacing arduino with processing

Tags: processing, arduino-uno

```java
import processing.serial.*;
 String COM5;
Serial myPort;
String val;

void setup() {
 String portName=COM5;
 myPort= new Serial(this,portName,9600);
}
void draw() {
 if(myPort.available()>0){
   val=myPort.readStringUntil('\n');
 }
 println(val);
}
```

This is my code, I have copied from a website. when I try running it is showing

> ***Error opening serial port null:null not permitted***

I am badly in need of answer to go forward in my thermal imaging project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can a web page read from the user's serial port - in the year 2017?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171522/how-can-a-web-page-read-from-the-users-serial-port-in-the-year-2017)

Comment: @combo_ci Please notice the [tag:processing] tag. This is a question about how to use Processing. Not a question about creating a web page.

Answer (score 0):

You never give `COM5` a value, so it's `null`. Then you pass that into the `Serial()` constructor. The `Serial()` constructor doesn't know what do do with a `null` value, so you get the error.

Please take a step back and read a tutorial on using the Serial library. The [official documentation](https://processing.org:8443/reference/libraries/serial/Serial.html) contains example code that uses the `Serial()` constructor correctly.

Answer (score 0):

`COM5` hasn't got a value as a String.
Try this in Processing:

```
import processing.serial.*;
Serial myPort;
String val;

void setup() {
  myPort= new Serial(this, "COM5", 9600);
}
void draw() {
  if (myPort.available()>0) {
    val=myPort.readStringUntil('\n');
  }
  println(val);
}
```

Double check your Arduino appears as COM5 in Device Manager and you don't have Arduino's Serial Monitor open when you run the Processing sketch.