# How to develop a web application that can read/write data to/from serial ports via browser?

Tags: browser, uwp, serial-port, windows-10, tablet

How to develop a web application that can read/write data to/from serial ports via browser?

Currently, I have a SPA that needs to access serial port data on windows 10 tablet.
There are some suggested solutions to develop an intermediate app. 
For example chrome app, window native services, and WebSocket.
Chrome app seems not good to me because I need to also target different browsers. 
Window Native Service and WebSocket seems to be a very good choice because it provides more control as it is natively supported. However, I am not sure if window services are supported in Windows 10 tablet.
Are there any other alternatives?

Comment: If you refer to my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15226241/403671 when I say "windows service", you can in fact replace it by some process that you can communicate with and has sufficient access to serial port.

Comment: If your tablet supports serial, then you should look into [johnny-five](http://johnny-five.io/) as it could be a plausible solution. There are other suggestions [here](https://libraries.io/search?keywords=serialport&languages=JavaScript)

Comment: Web apps run in a browser and cannot access windows APIs, so it is either Chome web app or native app, and you need to make up your mind.  But yes, UWP app, for Win 10 S tablets, can still [access serial port](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.serialcommunication).  If you insist of a web frontend on Win 10 S, though, you may want a UWP app service instead of native service.  Note that not all tablets are Win 10 S.  My Miix 520 is full Windows, while its successor Miix 630 is not.

Comment: You could install an application that forwards a serial port to a TCP port on the machine. With that, you could read and write to the serial port using something like localhost:7000. Check the following link for more details: https://gist.github.com/DraTeots/e0c669608466470baa6c

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar need few months ago and went for a simple python script that acts as a **bridge** between the WebSocket stream and the serial data.

Python can run on Windows 10 Tablet and has easy to use modules to handle websockets and serial port.

https://pypi.org/project/websockets/
https://pypi.org/project/pyserial/